# Spring Boot Jedis RedisConnectionFailureException Caused By UnknownHostException

Tags: java, kubernetes, redis, jedis, coredns

I am not a Java Developer (or english speaker) but I need some clues about this problem.

## The problem:

There is a Redis on Kubernetes working as a cache (on redis-master.redis.svc.cluster.local) and my application in other namespace. When it tries to connect to redis, it fails as "org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException" caused by "redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException" caused by "java.net.UnknownHostException".

Any help?

## Plataform:

EKS 1.28
Containerd Engine 1.7.2
Amazon Linux 2
Java 21.0.2
Spring Boot 3.2.1
Redis 7.2.1

Its funny, because when i exec a bash inside the container its resolves the name and connect to redis. I run curl, nslookup or redis-cli, and all works! Hostname always resolve. I even try to use the IP address on application but still the same problem.

Comment: If you can resolve the name from within the container, then I suspect your application isn't getting the right setting (e.g.: the host name). How do you make the connection information available to your Pod and subsequently your application?

Comment: @AmirKeibi I use variables to it by secret. And this variables are passed by src/main/resources/application.yml file.